# How to pass the picked date from showDatePicker() to a textField without using any other hacks in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, widget, state-management

*I want to pick a date from the calendarIcon(which is implemented with the showDatePicker()) inside a textField widget and feed it to the textField. But it is not working. And I want to manage the UI states using Provider. I Am showing my code below. Am I doing it wrong? or Is there another way to do it.*

**I tried doing the following way:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SignUp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final validator = Provider.of<SignUpController>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo FormValidation Provider"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: TextEditingController()..text = "Enter DOB",
              onChanged: (text) => {validator.date},
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today_sharp),
                  onPressed: () => {validator.showCalender(context)},
                ),
              ),
            )
          ])),
    );
  }
}

class SignUpController with ChangeNotifier {
  Future<DateTime> showCalender(BuildContext context) {
    notifyListeners();
    return showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    );
  }

  var date = DateTime.now().toString().split(' ')[0];
  void getDate(BuildContext context) async {
    var dateL = await showCalender(context);
    date = (dateL.toLocal()).toString().split(' ')[0];
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!**

**Finally did it..**

Reference: [For more information refer to this **medium.com** article by **Pinkesh Darji**](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-datepicker-in-flutter-37e84f7d8d6c)

**Solution**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// UI class
class SignUp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final validator = Provider.of<SignUpController>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo FormValidation Provider"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: TextEditingController(
                  text: validator.selectedDate == null
                      ? "Enter Date Of Birth"
                      : "${validator.selectedDate}".split(' ')[0]),
              onChanged: (String value) {
                validator.changeDOB(value);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                errorText: validator.dob.error,
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today_sharp),
                  onPressed: () => {validator.selectDate(context)},
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              // The ElevatedButton inherits the color of the app.
              child: Text("Submit"),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                print("Date: " + "${validator.selectedDate}".split(' ')[0]);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Controller Class
class SignUpController with ChangeNotifier {
  ValidationItem _dob = ValidationItem(null, null);

  // Getters
  ValidationItem get dob => _dob;
  // making the showDatePicker method
  DateTime selectedDate;
  selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
      // initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.year,
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      selectedDate = picked;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // Setters
  void changeDOB(String value) {
    try {
      // converting the DateTime data type into a String data type and only getting the
      // Date(discarding the time)
      value = selectedDate.toString().split(' ')[0];
      _dob = ValidationItem(value, null);
    } catch (error) {
      _dob = ValidationItem(null, "Use Correct Format");
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

// Model Class
class ValidationItem {
  final String value;
  final String error;

  ValidationItem(this.value, this.error);
}
```

*NOTE01:* *You can use multiple consumers for the provider (or maybe not??)*

*NOTE02:* *Above answer will not make the initial text(TextEditingController) editable. It can be achieved using the EditableText widget or maybe some other functions. Try it.*

Answer (score 0):

define a TextEditingController then pass data to it like this:

```
//define
TextEditingController text = TextEditingController(text:'');

//pass data
text = TextEditingController(text:data);
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying? Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

first, make ur widget stateful then add didChangeDependebcies() method it will listen.

```
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    setState(() {
      getImages();
    });
  }

  
  Future getImages() async {
    //get ur data here from provider
  }
```

Comment: I edited the answer and gave a specific example to check my answer again.